# Ruby On Rails 7 - how to call javascript function from controller and pass variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onclick, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a js file in *app -> javascript -> scripts -> script_scripts.js*
Inside I have some functions to test whether they are connected and yes they are connected:

In the code below, id"create" works, the id:"func" eventlistener works, but what I learnt from this was that the javascript fires before the controller gets called so, @txt is never created for the id:"funner" eventlistener and I don't know how to use the onclick to execute a function in rails 7.

So, what I want is either a way to call function so that the controller would execute first to set the variable, or call the js file from the controller.

Inside the scrip_scripts.js I have:

```js
function fun() {
  alerts('<%= @txt %>')
};

function funs(txt) {
  alerts(txt)
};

document.getElementById('funner').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("<%= @txt %>")
});

document.getElementById('func').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("TADA")
});

var test = document.getElementById('create').innerHTML = "Hello World! In script.js Test";
```

Inside my html.erb folder I have:

```rb
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "script" %>
<% end %>

<%= 
  button_to "Click Me", 
  home_test_path,
  onclick:"fun()"
%>

<%= 
  button_to "Click Me", 
  home_test_path,
  onclick:"funs(#{@txt})"
%>

<%= 
  button_to "Click Me", 
  home_test_path,
  id:"funner"
%>

<%= 
  button_to "Click Me", 
  home_test_path,
  id:"func"
%>

<div id="create"></div>
```

Inside the home controller I have the test method that has the @txt variable:

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  test
    @txt = "YAY"
  end
end
```

Comment: A couple of mistakes: Firstly, your `scrip_scripts.js` file is a pure javascript file, meaning you can't use ruby code in it, e.g. your `<%= @txt %>`. Secondly, all ruby code is executed at the server side. As soon as the html and js files are loaded, they are on the client side and only client code can affect them (javascript). Your func would thus never work, not even in a .rb.js file.

Comment: @JeroenVerfaillie Damn, that server side execution brings up another list of problems that I would deal with later. For now, when I click the button it is supposed to go to a new page called test from the index page, so all the codes would have to reload. I suppose the alerts would not be seen when fired since they would execute on the test page, but what I want is to be able to send in the variables to the script. Is changing the js from a pure .js to a rb.js the way to go? If so, how do you pin it in rails 7 importmap